# Get main Assembly name in referenced library which is injected into main Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I have `MySolution.MyLibrary` class library which I register in `MySolution.MyService` WCF service using SimpleInjector:

```
container.Register<IMyLibrary, MyLibrary>(LifeStyle.Singleton);
```

I need to get the name of the main assembly, `MySolution.MyService`, in the constructor of `MySolution.MyLibrary`. I've tried Assembly.* methods but I couldn't manage to do it. Any ideas how I can get the name?

These are what I've tried:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().FullName
"MySolution.MyLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"

Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().FullName
"Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"

Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
null
```

Comment: What is the concept "main assembly"?

Comment: _Why_ does this component need to know about the application's entry point assembly? What is your goal here?

Comment: @Steven: it's a logger. The filename is set at the constructor and I'd like to create the log file as MySolution.MyService.txt.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

...

StackFrame[] frames = new StackTrace().GetFrames();
string initialAssembly = (from f in frames 
                          select f.GetMethod().ReflectedType.AssemblyQualifiedName
                         ).Distinct().Last();
```

[Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014280/c-sharp-getting-parent-assembly-name-of-calling-assembly)

**Update** :

Use below Code for WCF:

```
var currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var callerAssemblies = new StackTrace().GetFrames()
            .Where(x => x.GetMethod() != null && x.GetMethod().ReflectedType != null )
                    .Select(x => x.GetMethod().ReflectedType.Assembly).Distinct()
                    .Where(x => x.GetReferencedAssemblies().Any(y => y.FullName == currentAssembly.FullName));
        var initialAssembly1 = callerAssemblies.Last();
```

[image]

Comment: Last() gives me System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime, probably because it's hosted with IISExpress. MySolution.MyService is like 7th in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply inject this information:

```
public class MyLibrary : IMyLibrary
{
    public MyLibrary(string assemblyName) { ... }
}
```

By registering it as follows:

```
container.RegisterSingleton<IMyLibrary>(new MyLibrary(
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().FullName));
```

Or in case you need to use *Auto-Wiring* (because `MyLibrary` contains other dependencies, extract the configuration value into a configuration object:

```
public class MyLibraryConfig
{
    public readonly string AssemblyName;

    public MyLibraryConfig(string assemblyName) { 
        this.AssemblyName = assemblyName;
    }
}

public class MyLibrary : IMyLibrary
{
    public MyLibrary(MyLibraryConfig config, IOtherDependency dep) { ... }
}
```

With the following configuration:

```
container.RegisterSingleton(new MyLibraryConfig(
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().FullName));

container.Register<IMyLibrary, MyLibrary>(Lifestyle.Singleton)
```

Comment: I thought you were against passing runtime parameters to injected object constructor :) https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/58#issuecomment-111715956 . I'm looking for a more "automatic" solution, e.g I rather not bother referer with obligatory parameters but I'll change to this if I can't find a way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: A runtime parameter is a value that will change throughout the lifetime of the application. In this case the value is fixed and known after startup. That makes it rather a 'configuration' value, not a runtime value.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
MethodBase entryMethod = null;
var methodFrames = new StackTrace().GetFrames().Select(t => t.GetMethod()).ToList();
foreach (var method in methodFrames)
{
    if (method.Name == "Main" && method.ReturnType == typeof(void)){
        entryMethod = method;
    }
}
Assembly entryAssembly = entryMethod.Module.Assembly;
```

Haven't tested it though, the idea is to walk the methods until you find a known method from the library like the example looks for a Main method from a console app.